# Complex Contour Integral Involving Arg(z)

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration

My question is regarding the following complex integral:

$$\int_\gamma\frac{\operatorname{Arg}(z)}{z} dz$$

where $\gamma$ is the curve defined by:$\quad$ $\gamma(t) = e^{it}, 0\leq t\leq \frac{\pi}{2}$.

Below is my solution:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\int_\gamma\frac{\operatorname{Arg}(z)}{z} dz =& \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{t}{e^{it}}*ie^{it}dt \\
= & \; i\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2}tdt \\
=& \;\frac{\pi^2i}{8}
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I believe my attempt at this question is correct but the allowable multiple choice answers are:

a. $0$ $\quad$ b. $-\frac{i\pi}{2}$ $\quad$ c. $\frac{i\pi}{2}$ $\quad$ d. $\frac{\pi}{2}$ $\quad$ e. $\ln\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$

Is there an error in my work or maybe just a typo in the MC answers?

Thanks in advance for you help!

Comment: Well, I don't think you can continuously define $\text{Arg}$ along the unit circle since it encloses the origin. However, if you do define it as $$\text{Arg}(re^{i\theta})=\theta \mod 2\pi,$$, then I think your calculation is alright.

Comment: Your approach and final result are correct.

Comment: Did you try to write $Arg(z)$ as $arg(z)+2\pi k$, where $arg(z)$ is the principle argument and $k\in{\mathbb{Z}}^{+}$?

Comment: Upon further investigation, there seems to be an error in the mark scheme.